# Unable to show the provided content via the web or the installed version of the Facebook app. Some dialogs are only supported starting API 14

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-facebook, fbsdksharedialog

I am trying to upload image to wall from SD card in Android.

I am getting this error -
 **"Unable to show the provided content via the web or the installed version of the Facebook app. Some dialogs are only supported starting API 14."**

Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

Thanks

Looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: did you find the solution ??

Comment: Did you hear from anyone?